# How to call copy constructor of a caller class from pimpl class?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, pimpl-idiom

I just need to know if I want to call my copyconstuctor from pImpl class, how will I do it?
For example:

```
CImpl::SomeFunc()
{

//cloning the caller class instance

caller = new Caller(*this)// I cant do this since its a pImpl class

}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer a question which is not asked properly. Voted for close.

Comment: what i mean is i have a situation where i need to call copyconstructor of my caller class in its corresponding pImpl class.
How will I do it?

Comment: If you need to do that, your design is wrong to begin with.

Comment: Search for it...on this site...and google.

Comment: I am not able to find it.can you please provide some links?

Comment: Yogi: what is your implementation as of now?

Comment: Its like all my private data members are there in pImpl class. now i have to clone tht instance of a caller and return. I have a pImpl instace in my caller and i am doing copy and assignment for the pImpl in my caller class.so somehow i need to call tht copy constructor.

Comment: Also, if i call copy constructor of my pImpl class in pImpl only,then I face the problem of converting tht pImpl instance to my caller.
I hope you get my problem.

Comment: Why are you not implementing the copy constructor for the Caller class, where you could also make a hard copy of `m_pImpl` pointer? That is how it should be done. something like this : `Caller(Caller const & other) : m_pImpl(other.m_pImpl->Clone()) {}`

Comment: I have implemented copy constructor in the caller class
Caller(caller& val)
{
*pImpl = *val.pImpl
}
I just want this to be called from my pImpl class?

Comment: Yogi: Why you want it be called from pimpl class? Anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after reading your comments, it seems that you want to be able to provide the ability to make *copies* of `Caller` class. If so, then in that case you should implement the copy constructor for `Caller` class, where you can make a hard copy of `m_pImpl` pointer.

```
class CallerImpl;

class Caller
{
   std::shared_ptr<CallerImpl> m_pImpl;
public:
   Caller(Caller const & other) : m_pImpl(other.m_pImpl->Clone()) {}
   //...
};
```

And then you can implement `Clone()` function in `CallerImpl` class as:

```
class CallerImpl
{
   public:
     CallerImpl* Clone() const
     {
         return new CallerImpl(*this); //create a copy and return it
     }
     //...
};
```

Now you can make copy of `Caller`:

```
//Usage
Caller original;
Caller copy(original);
```

Comment: How do i call this copy constructor from my Pimpl class?

Comment: @Yogi: WHY WHY WHY? Why do you want it be called from `Pimpl` class? Why it is needed?

Comment: That is what is needed..I have everything in place.is it possible some how?if not then may be I need to change my design

Comment: @Yogi: As I said in the beginning of our conversation, that if you ever need to do that, then your design is wrong to begin with. And I don't even know how you're doing that, and why you need that. Your post gives no information regarding that.

Comment: hmm, Because all my implementation is moved to pImpl class. I am just caaling pImpl metods from corresponding caller methods. so one API is there which should return all instances of the caller class.so i need to clone instances with all data members and return.

Comment: @Yogi: Making a copy of the `Caller` object is equivalent to making a copy of `CallerImpl` object, isn't it? So when you make a copy of `Caller` class, which in turn makes a copy of the underlying `m_pImpl` member, as shown in my answer. Did you see and understand my code?

Comment: @Yogi: Also, why do you have a method in `Caller` which makes a copy? Why can't you use copy-constructor for that?